# Lookup a Dataframe column that has rows of lists with list and return matching column value of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried the method suggested in [Lookup a Dataframe column with list and return list matching the row of another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71619015/lookup-a-dataframe-column-with-list-and-return-list-matching-the-row-of-another) to look up the column value,`Col1` that has the elements in the `query` list matching `Col2`, but faced with

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['watermelon', 'grape'], dtype='object', name='Col1')] are in the [index]"
```

Code used

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Jack', 'Mary', 'Andrew'], 
                   'Col2': [['apple', 'banana', 'papaya', 'tomato'],['berry', 'juice', 'watermelon'], ['cabbage', 'grape']]})

query = ['watermelon', 'grape']

q = df.set_index('Col1').loc[query]
```

Expecting

```
   Col1
0  Mary
1  Andrew
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Jack', 'Mary', 'Andrew'], 
                   'Col2': [['apple', 'banana', 'papaya', 'tomato'],['berry', 'juice', 'watermelon'], ['cabbage', 'grape']]})

query = ['watermelon', 'grape']
df_x = df.explode('Col2')
df_x.set_index('Col2').loc[query].reset_index(drop=True)
```

And this is the output -

```
    Col1
0   Mary
1   Andrew
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggested method won't work for your query, because you want the opposite.
`loc` is a function to query an index, not a column. Ie. the query can be something within this list `['Jack', 'Mary', 'Andrew']`, which is why you are facing an error.

Also, unlike the dataframe from the suggested method, your column contains nested list:

```
     Col1                             Col2
0    Jack  [apple, banana, papaya, tomato]
1    Mary       [berry, juice, watermelon]
2  Andrew                 [cabbage, grape]
```

As far as I understand, you want to find those `Col1` values where `Col2` matches one of the queries. We can create a new Pandas Series, by applying a function that will search if the fruit is in the query.

```py
df_ = df.set_index('Col1')['Col2'].apply(lambda fruits: any([f in query for f in fruits]))
```

Output:

```py
print(df_[df_].reset_index()['Col1'])

0      Mary
1    Andrew
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

Let me know if this was your intention.